# Spring data Jpa findTop and findFirst generating error Incorrect syntax near '@P0'

Tags: sql-server-2012, spring-data-jpa, jpa-2.1, hibernate-5.x

I am using spring data JPA 1.8.2 and trying to get top result. I am using the following method

```
LearningSession findTopBySourceAndExternalLmsSessionIdAndCourseCodeAndLearnerEnrollmentEnrollmentStatusOrderByIdAsc(String source, String externalLmsSessionId, String courseCode, String enrollmentStatus);
```

I tried also by removing OrderBy

```
LearningSession findTopBySourceAndExternalLmsSessionIdAndCourseCodeAndLearnerEnrollmentEnrollmentStatus(String source, String externalLmsSessionId, String courseCode, String enrollmentStatus);
```

In both cases hibernate is generating the following query. Just use `*` for every thing. For order by in the end `order by learningse0_.id asc`

```
select TOP ?  learningse0_.*
from LearningSession learningse0_ 
left outer join LearnerEnrollment learnerenr1_ on learningse0_.ENROLLMENT_ID=learnerenr1_.id 
where learningse0_.source=?
and learningse0_.externalLmsSessionId=?
and learningse0_.courseCode=?
and learnerenr1_.enrollmentStatus=?
```

Query is right But I am getting the following exception

```
Hibernate: select TOP ?  learningse0_.id as id1_47_, learningse0_.brandName as brandNam2_47_, learningse0_.courseApprovalId as courseAp3_47_, learningse0_.courseCode as courseCo4_47_, learningse0_.endTime as endTime5_47_, learningse0_.externalLmsSessionId as external6_47_, learningse0_.externalLmsUrl as external7_47_, learningse0_.isCourseMessageDisplay as isCourse8_47_, learningse0_.LANGUAGE_ID as LANGUAG15_47_, learningse0_.LEARNER_ID as LEARNER16_47_, learningse0_.ENROLLMENT_ID as ENROLLM17_47_, learningse0_.learningSessionGuid as learning9_47_, learningse0_.lmsProvider as lmsProv10_47_, learningse0_.redirectUrl as redirec11_47_, learningse0_.source as source12_47_, learningse0_.startTime as startTi13_47_, learningse0_.uniqueUserGuid as uniqueU14_47_ from LearningSession learningse0_ left outer join LearnerEnrollment learnerenr1_ on learningse0_.ENROLLMENT_ID=learnerenr1_.id where learningse0_.source=? and learningse0_.externalLmsSessionId=? and learningse0_.courseCode=? and learnerenr1_.enrollmentStatus=? order by learningse0_.id asc
13:53:47.686 [main] DEBUG org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper - could not extract ResultSet [n/a]
com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: Incorrect syntax near '@P0'          
com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException.makeFromDatabaseError(SQLServerException.java:216) ~[sqljdbc4-4.0.jar:?]
```

What I am doing wrong ? I tried `First`, `Top1`, `First1` but result is error. Please help.

Thanks

Comment: Did you try to use the `@Query(...)` annotation? I think it would simplify this quite a bit.

Comment: hhm I tried. But I think I can't do it like in JPA `select top 1 ..` . Finally I used native query using `@Query` and things are working now but point is what is wrong with this method. It is generating right query but getting exception ...  `Do I need to extends my Repository with Paging or Sorting provided by Spring-Data-JPa ?` Currently my Repository only extending CrudRepository.

Comment: JpaRepository extends all of them I believe. The only thing that I can think of is it might be a case issue or spelling related. It was very long and to me that would be harder to maintain than an annotated query.

Answer (score 8):

Not sure if this will work for you, but I ran into the same error and after a lot of digging I figured out that I was using SqlServerDialect in my JpaVendorAdapter, and when I changed it to be more specifically for SqlServer2012 (SqlServerDialect2012) the error went away:

```
<bean id="jpaVendorAdapter"
    class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaVendorAdapter">
    <property name="database" value="SQL_SERVER" />
    <property name="databasePlatform" value="org.hibernate.dialect.SQLServer2012Dialect" />
    <property name="showSql" value="true" />
</bean>
```

Comment: Thank you SOOO much. Was exactly what I needed when I hit this issue on a Spring update.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue with Hibernate 5 + Spring Data.
Changing the Dialect to SQLServer2012Dialect worked for me.

public class SQLServerNativeDialect extends SQLServer2012Dialect

For reference::
https://hibernate.atlassian.net/browse/HHH-10032

Thanks,